# What is Psake used for?

Tags: continuous-integration, build-automation, psake

Buliding the C# solution or Build automation script ..If its for Building the solution why it has to use MSbuild for it.. And clean will also be scripted in it intially

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**[Psake](https://github.com/psake/psake)** is generally a steer away from XML based build scripts.

Since Psake is a PowerShell module and Powershell is a scripting language built on top of .NET, you have access to the entire .NET framework to easily be able to write custom build scripts.

Psake calls MSBuild to build .NET projects because projects are `.proj` files (or language variant `.proj` files) and contain all of the project data and metadata in a structure that MSBuild engine understands. You could certainly manage calling the compiler and do all the leg work yourself but that would be reinventing the wheel.

Psake's true power comes in being able to easily extend the build script using a fast and powerful programming language.